# Spring 4: Individual view layouts depending on request

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller, tiles

I am using Spring 4 MVC to display serve my web page. I now want to display the **same content** with **different layouts** wrapped around the body/content depending on the current HttpServletRequest (e.g. `request.getServerName()`). This means **https://page1.test/page.html** will be mapped to the same controller as **https://page2.test/page.html** and returns the same content depending on the controller logic, but **page1.test** draws for example a different header and footer.

As far as I know, Spring MVC is not capable of doing this. I am now planing to use Apache Tiles 3 or JSP 2.0 tags to do this. Is there any best practice and how can I do this (Spring Java Config is preferred)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a read of http://tech.finn.no/2012/07/25/the-ultimate-view-tiles-3/ just to see how far you can push Tiles-3

Indeed it can solve what you're after.

(That blog website has just been migrated from wordpress to github pages so some of the code snippets require horizontal scrolling, we're still cleaning these small formatting issues up so please excuse them)

Comment: Thank you, this blog entry helped a lot. I used a custom Renderer implementation to solve this problem.